# Factory method only called once

Tags: unity-container, constructor-injection

Following is my register code

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                        new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                        new InjectionParameter<IBar2>(CreateBar2(container)))
```

Problem is `CreateBar2(container)` is only called once when program startup, I need it called everytime IFoo resolved

Another question, which one is best practice

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                        new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                        new InjectionParameter<IBar2>(CreateBar2(container)))
```

or

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                        new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                        CreateBar2(container))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use a different [LifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx). [TransientLifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.transientlifetimemanager.aspx) will resolve a new instance every time.

```
    container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                        new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                            new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                            new InjectionParameter<IBar2>(CreateBar2(container)), 
                            new TransientLifetimeManager())
```

This means that every time `IFoo` is injected or resolved it will call the constructor each time. However, it seems as you're injecting a method, which will be executed at registration - `CreateBar2(container)`. It's the same thing as writing:

```
var bar2 = CreateBar2(container); // Called once.
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                        new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                        new InjectionParameter<IBar2>(bar2))
```

I recomend you to abstract this to a class instead and injecting it. This way you can control the calls to that as well.

```
public interface ICreateBar2
{
    IBar CreateBar2();
}

public class CreateBar2
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public CreateBar(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IBar CreateBar2()
    {
        // Do stuff.
        return CreateBar2(_container); // Or what you need to do?
    }
}
```

And change your registration to

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                        new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                        new ResolvedParameter<ICreateBar2>),
                        new TransientLifetimeManager())

container.RegisterType<ICreateBar2, CreateBar2>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Or possibly [RegisterInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648449.aspx), if it better suits your needs?

Remember to change the constructor of `IFoo` to accept `ICreateBar` instead. The best thing with this approach is that you don't need the `InjectionConstructor` anymore, since all parameters can be resolved by `Unity`.

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

If your REALLY need to keep the `CreateBar2()`-method in the current scope, you can inject a `Func` which actually returns the same value as `CreateBar2()`.

I do not know the complete signature of CreateBar(), but you can do something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof (IEnumerable<int>),
                        new ResolvedParameter<IBar1>,
                        new InjectionParameter<Func<IBar2>>(
                            new Func<IBar2>(()=> CreateBar2(container)));
```

But now you need to inject `Func<IBar2>` to the `IFoo` constructor. This will cause it to execute whenever you use it in the constructor.

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    IBar1 _bar1;
    IBar2 _bar2;

    public Bar(IBar1 bar1, Func<IBar2> bar2Func)
    {
        _bar1 = bar1;
        _bar2 = bar2Func();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using factory injecting helped,  LifetimeManager didn't and as I know the default type is TransientLifetimeManager.